# How to get 'latitiude' and "longitude' fields from Twilio Studio Whatsapp messages

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-studio

I have integrated my Twilio whatsapp number with Twilio Studio and Twilio Flex correctly, that is all working fine.
But when sending a location pin from Whatsapp and checking the message parameters inside Twilio Studio the 'longitude' and 'latitiude' parameters have been dropped by Twilio somehow.

If I were to route the messages directly to my API (can't be used as an actual solution right now) I can see that Twilio is receiving these parameters but not passing them to Twilio Studio.

I need to be able to access these fields for my chatbot.
Any help would GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: When you set your Twilio WhatsApp webhook to a new Studio flow (using the Studio Webhook URL displayed when clicking on the Trigger Widget) in your account, you still don't see Latitude/Longitude? I tested this out and I am receiving those two keys. 

Note, it looks like you cannot use Flex to send in these WhatsApp location attributes, https://www.twilio.com/blog/whatsapp-and-flex-in-minutes-html, as the message is routed through Twilio Proxy.

Comment: Hey Alan, thaks for the response, using that method does pass the latitude/longitude fields but using that method stops the Flex integration from working unfortunately because it isn't getting sent through the task router.

Comment: Does this have a solution to keep using Twilio Studio and get access to the GEO attributes? I can't find anything related to this on Twilio Docs